# Google Apps Script: Finding text and setting cursor to found text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I would like to setCursor to the location that is returned by findText.

Here is what I am trying:

```
    var position = doc.newPosition(foundElement.getElement(), foundElement.getStartOffset());
    doc.setCursor(position);
```

But, the cursor does not move. Even with the simple examples like

```
 //setting cursor at the beginning of the doc
 var paragraph = doc.getBody().getChild(0);
 var position = doc.newPosition(paragraph.getChild(0), 0);
 doc.setCursor(position);
```

findText returns a rangelement, while document.setCursor expects a position. How do I go from rangeelement to position? :)

This got me halfway to the solution [Finding text (multiple times) and highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478471/finding-text-multiple-times-and-highlighting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried this code and it is perfectly setting the cursor in the beginning of the found text.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var paragraph = doc.getBody().getChild(0);
  var foundElement = doc.getBody().findText("text");
  var position = doc.newPosition(foundElement.getElement(), foundElement.getStartOffset());
    doc.setCursor(position);
}
```

Hope that helps!