# check if portion of paragraph is hyperlinked in Google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

This is how I select my paragraph in my Google doc

```
let document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
let paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
let paragraph = paragraphs[5];
```

Now how do I check if there is a URL linked on the portion of the paragraph from index/position `start` to `end`?

For example, if the paragraph were

Hello darkness my [old friend](https://stackoverflow.com)

then it should return true for the positions 19 to 23 because that portion of text links to stackoverflow.

There is the method `paragraph.editAsText().getLinkUrl()` but it doesn't take the indices/positions as parameters.

Please help

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944926/11225291

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findURL() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
  var text = paragraphs[0].getText();
  var child = paragraphs[0].getChild(0).asText();
  //Storing words in an array
  var words = text.match(/\S+/g);
  //check if array is empty
  if (words) {
    //iterate each words
    words.forEach(word => {
      //use findtext and getStartOffset to find the start position of string
      //use getLinkUrl(offset) to check if the word has link on it.
      if(child.getLinkUrl(child.findText(word).getStartOffset())){
        //print the position of words that has link.
        //added +1 since the start of count in getStartOffset() is zero.
        Logger.log(child.findText(word).getStartOffset()+1);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Example:

[image]

Output:

[image]

### References:

- [findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findtextsearchpattern)
- [getLinkUrl(offset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getlinkurloffset)